# server side user input validation - class design*

Tags: php

I test user input both the client and server side.  On the server side there is a short simple class composed of static functions which validate user input.  Class sign-up and sign-in call these functions.  My concern is that I should not be using static functions.  Should I be using static functions to validate user input?  Thanks.

```
/*check*/

class check 
{
    static function empty_user($a)
    {
        return (int)!in_array('',$a); 
    }   

    static function name($a)
    {
        return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z-\.\s]{1,40}$/',$a);
    }

    static function email($a)
    {
        return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9._s-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$/',$a);
    }

    static function pass($a)
    {
        return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,20}$/',$a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the class is ultimately not relevant for the decision about static vs. non-static member functions. What matters if objects of the class has a *state*, or if the class is merely a stand-in for a namespace.

In the latter case, the class just collects a bunch of loosely related function in a common namespace, but you would never instantiate the class. In the former case, you should put all the data that's common to the design purpose of the class *into* the class as private members and use those members in your (non-static) functions.

In your example, I could see that you make `$a` a private member:

```
class CheckInput
{
    private $data;

    public function init($a) { $this->data = $a; } // or write a constructor

    public function email() { ... $this->data ... }

    // ...
}
```

That way, you instantiate one `CheckInput` object for each set of input data.

Comment: so do you think i should do this?  Then I have to write two lines of code to call the function correct? One to instantiate the object and one to call the function.

Comment: @Chris: Well, you instantiate once, and then you keep calling the member functions for whatever purpose you have in mind. The advantage is that you don't need to keep passing the (potentially large) data structure around. Ultimately this is really a matter of taste, though. Whatever you find cleanest and easiest to maintain.

Comment: i think not then...b.c. each user user input - name, email, password, etc. uses a different check function...there is not realy any "shared use"...it's not like I have a large array that I call multiple functions to work on the array...i have about 32 characters of text that I'm running a regex on and that's it...actually i do see some benefit in sharing the $a as check_empty is used as well as the validation...that way a local variable is not created,released,created,released...it is created...released...hence some is saved...

Comment: ...hence...object oriented sytyle allows you to consolidate local variable creattion...as one benefit...correct?

Comment: @Chris: You would still implement all those separate check functions. It'd look almost identical to your current design, only that the data variable is no longer a function argument. But it's up to you, and there's nothing wrong with your current design. If you end up requiring further stateful logic for your validation, perhaps you'll find the stateful class more useful, but at the moment it's only a small difference.

Comment: @Chris: What's morally more important is that you encapsulate everything that pertains to one task (user validation) into one object, so that you never have to pass multiple coupled pieces of data around. It's not so obvious here because you only have one single argument, but imagine you had two or three variables. Then you'd have to pass those at every call, causing much more coupling than necessary.

Comment: ... and another thing: strong encapsulation makes it easier if you should at some point decide to replace the whole thing by a totally different validation method. If you just say `$user->email()`, then you never have to worry about how that's implemented, and the actual class can be replaced without any impact on the other code.

Comment: It's not "in the cloud", it's in the object! When you say `$userinput = new CheckInput; $userinput->init($a);`, then the data gets stored in the `$userinput` object. Thenceforth all member functions can access it.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is if this is just a Utility class then static functions should do the job.